# генерация нового slick слайдера для новой карточки товара

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slick.js

Использую слайдер slick для карточки товара.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы для каждой новой карточки автоматически генерировался персональный слайдер.

Сама карточка довольно объемная.
Просто ее пример

```
<div class = "card" data-pid="1">
    <div class = "wrapper" id="slickSlider">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
    </div>
    <div class = "wrapper2" id="slickSlider2">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
    </div>
</div>
```

и сам slick

```
$(function(){
    $('#SlickSlider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        vertical: true,
        infinite: false,
        asNavFor:"#SlickSlider2"
    });

    $('#SlickSlider2').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        infinite: false,
        asNavFor:"#SlickSlider"
    });
});
```

Comment: ну так краткий пример верстки и навешивания слика в студию. а то я могу вам написать, что `$(".card").slick(...)` но толку то не будет, наверное?

Comment: @teran Обновил вопрос

Comment: что-то подозреваю что один из `asNavFor` у вас лишний. Относительно сути вопроса - я так опнимаю, приведен пример одной карточки, и их у вас таких несколько?

Comment: @teran да, карточек таких много

Answer (score 1):

я так подозреваю, что у вас есть какой-то цикл по карточкм, и там меняется `data-pid`. Вот его можно использовать для формирования `id` блоков. Получите что-то вроде

```
<div class = "card" data-pid="1">
    <div class = "wrapper slick" id="slick_1">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
    </div>
    <div class = "wrapper2 slick-nav" id="slick_nav_1">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
        <img class = "img">
    </div>
</div>
```

далее перебираете все `.card` и вешаете обработчики

```
 $(".card").each(function(){
      let pid = $(this).data('pid');

      $(`#slick_${pid}`).slick(...);
      $(`#slick_nav_${pid}`).slick({
         asNavFor: `#slick_${pid}`,
      });
 });
```

Хотя в целом, основные слайды можно добавить без цикла через `$(".slick").slick(...)`  а вот навигации уже в цикле.